# addField and populate a document in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

I am trying to add a field through aggregate func. And then populating that document with some fields. But it seems after aggregation i cannot populate.

```
    concert = await Concert.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          _id: concert._id,
        },
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          withdrawalAmt: total.price,
        },
      },
    ]);

    const populateReviews = await concert.populate({
    path: "reviews",
    options: {
      sort: { rating: -1, updatedAt: -1 },
    },
    populate: {
      path: "customerId",
      options: {
        select: { name: 1, avatar: 1 },
      },
    },
  });
```

Here `reviews` are vitually populating. It gives the error message of `concert.populate is not a func`.
Could you please tell me how do i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `populate` on a model.

It should be

```
Model.populate(concert, {path: "reviews"})
```